# Unable to connect to mongodb service from another service

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

OS: MacOS mojave

```
version: '3.1'

services:  
  apiWithKubernetesMongodb:
    container_name: apiWithKubernetesMongodb
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    expose:
      - "27018"
    command: --bind_ip_all --port 27018
    hostname: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongousradmin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongopassadmin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    networks:
      - apinet

  apiWithKubernetes: 
    container_name: api_with_kubernetes
    image: sherryummen/api_with_kubernetes:v1
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - apinet
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/api_with_kubernetes
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - apiWithKubernetesMongodb
    links:
      - apiWithKubernetesMongodb

networks:
  apinet:
    driver: bridge
```

```golang
const (
    HOST           = "apiWithKubernetesMongodb"
    PORT           = 27018
    DBNAME         = "service_db"
    COLLECTIONNAME = "user_info"
    ROOTUSER       = "mongousradmin"
    ROOTPASSWORD   = "mongopassadmin"
)
```

```golang
client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/admin", ROOTUSER, ROOTPASSWORD, HOST, PORT)))
```

I have thee above docker file and go api which should connect to mongodb.

But my go code gives error "server selection timeout\ncurrent topology: Type: Unknown\nServers:\nAddr: apiwithkubernetesmongodb:27018, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(apiwithkubernetesmongodb:27018[-249]) connection is closed"

**Note: For those who stumble to this, it was all about casing of the name of the service, after switching to all lower case naming, it starts working.**

Comment: Just a wild guess, but could you try to use all lowercase names for the services?

Comment: try to remove `hostname` option from configuration

Comment: hey @MarkusWMahlberg thanks. That was it. I changed it to all lower and it starts working. I did not see that mentioned anywhere, but also I haven't read all the documentation , but I did find lot of unresolved issues on github related to casing. Btw how did you guess it?

Comment: The error message. The name was all lowercase. Since it did not get the service by that name, my assumption was that the hostname was taken literally from the service name. Which turned out to be true ;).  This seems like a bug in docker to me - I would have to read up, but iirc, DNS is supposed to be case insensitive.